# Геокодер Yandex. Как получить ближайшее метро от адреса на php?

Tags: php, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api, геокодинг

Брал всю инфу от сюда https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/#input_params__example

Токен получил тут - https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/services/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
$parameters = array(
  'apikey' => 'f731a89f-4492-43ff-a822-9de189c2f71e',
  'geocode' => 'Москва,+улица+Габричевского,+8',
  'kind' => 'metro',
  'results' => '1'
);

$response = file_get_contents('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?'. http_build_query($parameters));
```

Вот такой ответ я получаю, вывожу через print_r (через echo тоже самое).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если взять пример с документации.

`https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&geocode=37.611347,55.760241&kind=metro&results=1`

Это работает и метро показывает. Я посмотрел где эти координаты, они вообще в Иране.
А когда у себя в коде вставляю или координаты, или адрес - метро нету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл решение.
Касаемо Ирана, координаты на карте просто не правильно воспринимались (там было 37.611347,55.760241, а надо было 55.760241,37.611347 то-есть поменять местами, а так всё хорошо).

У меня не получалось, потому-что почему-то по адресу, он не хотел показывать метро. Но если вставить координаты, то показывал. По этому первый запрос мы делаем что-бы получить координаты, а второй - чтобы получить метро.

```
    $address = 'Самара,улица+22+Партсъезда,+15';
    $parameters = array(
      'apikey' => 'token',
      'geocode' => $address, # Самара,улица+22+Партсъезда,+15
      'format' => 'json'
    );

    $response = file_get_contents('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?'. http_build_query($parameters));
    $obj = json_decode($response, true);

    $cord = str_replace(" ", ",", $obj['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['Point']['pos']);
    $parameters = array(
      'apikey' => 'token',
      'geocode' => $cord,
      'kind' => 'metro',
      'format' => 'json'
    );

    $response = file_get_contents('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?'. http_build_query($parameters));
    $obj = json_decode($response, true);

    $metro = $obj['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['name'];
    echo $metro;
```